# Open tabpage from another tabpage in C# (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, tabpage

Hey I want to open tabpage2 when i'm clicking a button in tabpage1.

How can I do it ? Thanks.

picture :

[image]

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? Show your effort first please.. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Also, please be more precise and describe the situation a bit further. By _open tabpage2_ do you mean _make it the active tab_ or _create it and make it the active tab_. Please also thoroughly identify the class you are using. Most of the experienced .NET+WinForms developers that might be able to give you the answer will unarguably presume it is [System.Windows.Forms.TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx) but unexperienced developers who could in the future benefit from your question might not.

Comment: ok i have 2 forms that opens in tabpage 1 and tabpage 2

now i want to do that when im clicking on button in form 1 , tab page 2 open (with form 2 in it )

i try search in google for help without success

Comment: Tab pages do not have forms "in" them. This question still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I edit my question , hope you will understand what i ment.. @CodyGray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and your image are two different requests.

For the image, you can use your own event on Form2:

```
public event EventHandler OpenSecondTabPage;

public Form2() {
  InitializeComponent();
  button1.Click += button1_Click;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  OnOpenSecondTabPage();
}

protected void OnOpenSecondTabPage() {
  if (OpenSecondTabPage != null) {
    OpenSecondTabPage(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

Then in your main form:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnShown(e);
  Form2 f2 = new Form2();
  f2.OpenSecondTabPage += f2_OpenSecondTabPage;
  f2.ShowDialog(this);
}

void f2_OpenSecondTabPage(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks 
And sorry for the bad question formulation